# Azure Worker with webapi Role Unexpected Restart

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-worker-roles

I've a worker role on a A7 Azure Worker role. The Role is a ASP Webapi.

When the role is running i can send it a command (via a web interface) which starts a data aggregation process which takes up to 8 hours.

In this time a big object graph is created.

This worked for monthes without any problems.

Now sometimes it seems like the role or the api is restarted in the middle of the creation.

One time i was able to observe it in the azure management portal and it looked like this:
[image]

But no restartes are in the protocolls.

Comment: Where does your data aggregation logic reside? In the Web API layer or in a separate process? And are you self-hosting WebAPI in your worker role, or using IIS? I ask because IIS isn't well-suited for an 8 hour, memory-intensive workload.

Comment: We just created a worker role with the default vs project template not sure what that configuration is madei n default

Comment: Is your Web API running in a *worker* role or a *web* role with IIS? (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/fundamentals-application-models/#tellmecs) If its a true worker role, then that's an okay choice to run an 8 hour task but you'd need to carefully separate the Web API layer from the long-running logic (typically using a separate role + queues). If its a web role then again that's not the place to run an 8 hour workload. In general I think you need to formally separate the Web API tier from the long-running logic. They should be in separate roles.

Comment: It is a Worker Role.

Comment: If you can post some code that shows how you're integrating Web API with your worker role and how your 8 hour workload executes, that might help. Or perhaps just further explain your design. We need more detail to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in contact with the azure support.

The result is that the instance was just too small to handle this hughe amount.

We switchted to a D14 instance and everything works like a charme

Comment: Can you add some details?  Were you literally using too much memory  and was that documented?  If Memory was the problem it should have showed up in your dashboard and been extremely simple to notice and track.  Did you find that you did not reach your limits but still somehow your worker was crashing?  A7 to D14 is $500 a month more, that is pretty intense...